# Get current rotation status of rotation animation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to build some kind of "Wheel of fortune" in PowerPoint (v. 16.43 for Mac). You can trigger a normal rotation animation for the wheel and when you click again, the rotation stops.

I want to get the degree of rotation from the animation using VBA.

Here is a minimal reproducible example in PowerPoint:

On the slide you have two shapes:

1. A rectangle "Button" used as a start and stop button
2. An arrow with the name "X", which is animated to spin

For the arrow "X" you set up two animations:

1. A "Spin" emphasis effect with the following options:

   - Effect Options:

     - Property: "360° Clockwise"
     - After Animation: "Don't Dim"
   - Timing:

     - Start: "On Click"
     - Duration: "1 seconds (Fast)"
     - Delay: 0
     - Repeat: "Until Next Click"
   - Triggers:

     - On click of: "Button"
2. An "Appear" entrance effect with the following options:

   - Effect Options:

     - After Animation: "Don't Dim"
   - Timing:

     - Start: "On Click"
     - Delay: 0
   - Triggers:

     - On click of: "Button"

Now when you start the presentation, you have the arrow "X" that starts to rotate when the "Button" is pressed and stops when it is pressed again.

My question now is: **How can I determine the rotation angle after the animation?**

With `SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.Shapes("X").Rotation` I get the rotation before the animation had started.

I can get the animation settings with

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences(1)(1).Behaviors(1).RotationEffect
```

But not the current rotation after the animation has stopped.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Can you not get the rotation after the animation stops with the same code as before it starts - *`SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.Shapes("X").Rotation`*?

Comment: No, after the animation I get the rotation before the animation.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [MCVE] - Without this it is extremely hard to troubleshoot your issue. I have done some testing and established 2 things - 1) using the `Shapes.Rotation` method will return the current rotation value at time of execution, 2) animations don't seem to *actually* change the rotation value.